# TestNG- pass parameters to the constructor where parameters are decided based on the testname

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I'm new to TestNG, here is my question..
I need to pass data to my @test methods via constructor, I've written the below code but getting a null pointer exception,

```
public class ParameterTests {
String x=null;
int y;

//no-arg constructor
public ParameterTests(){

}

@Factory(dataProvider="MyData")
public ParameterTests(String x, int y ){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}

@DataProvider(name = "MyData")
public Object[][] DataSupplier(Method meth) {

    Object[][] result = null;

    if (meth.getName().equals("Test1")) {
        result = new Object[][] {
            {"Test1-D1", 1 }, {"Test1-D2", 2 } 
        };

    } else if (meth.getName().equals("Test2")) {
        result = new Object[][] { 
            { "Test2-D3", 3 }, 
            { "Test2-D4", 4 } 
        };
    }

    return result;  

}


@Test//(dataProvider = "MyData")
public void Test1() {
 System.out.println(x + " " + y);
} 

@Test//(dataProvider = "MyData")
public void Test2() {
 System.out.println(x + " " + y);
} 

}
```

AND I am getting 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)

Comment: please dont declare a variable as null if value is assigned later to it

Comment: Hi Nishad.. it tried that as well but there was no difference.. I still get Nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

I did some modifications, split it into 2 classes, changed your constructor and dataprovider a bit, Hope this would help.

If you have specific test cases to be run with fixed data, configure different data providers for each test case.

Now if you want to select test cases to be run for a particular data use [IMethodInterceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors) or [IAnnotationTransformer](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) or [beanshell](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell) to decide test cases to be run.

```
package com.crazytests;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;

public class MyFactoryClass {

@DataProvider(name = "MyData")
public static Object[][] dp(ITestContext context, Method m) throws Exception {

    return new Object[][] { new Object[] { "Test1-D1", 1 }, new Object[] { "Test1-D2", 2 } };
}

@Factory(dataProvider = "MyData")
public Object[] createInstances(String x, int y) {
    return new Object[] { new ParameterTests(x, y) };
}
}
```

And the test class

```
package com.crazytests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ParameterTests {

private String x;
private int y;

public ParameterTests(String x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@Test
public void tetsCase1() {
    System.out.println(this.x + this.y);

}

@Test
public void tetsCase2() {
    System.out.println(this.x + this.y);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the method invoking the dataprovider is not your @Test method but the @Factory constructor.  And hence your meth instance is null, since it is a constructor invoking the dataprovider.  You can directly use your dataprovider on your methods.